# What's the difference between /etc/systemd/system/sshd.service and /etc/ssh/sshd_config

Tags: ssh, ubuntu-18.04

My guess is that sshd.service controls how the ssh service is started, and the sshd_config is how it is run.

Comment: systemd service are the service unit configuration files (https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html) /etc/ssh/sshd_config is the configuration of the sshd daemon

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, the two config files target different software.

`sshd_config` configures the behaviour of sshd, while `sshd.service` configures systemd to start it.